# EOF expected error when adding let statement to advanced editor

Tags: powerquery

I get this error when I add the let statement below the first let statement. I tried adding commas between them, but didn't work.
I'd like to add this second part cause I want to round the time of one of the columns in its minutes.

```
let
'some code here'
in
#"Duplicatas Removidas1"
'second let'
let
fun_RoundTime =
'more code here'
in
fun_RoundTime
```

Answer (score 0):

sample code for embedded function

```
let 
// some comment here since comments start with two slashes
Table1 = #table({"Key1"},{{"Auto"},{"Bus"},{"Autobus"}, {"Car"}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Table1, "Custom", each fn_Highest("ddd")),

fn_Highest =  (n as text) as text =>
   let Parent_ID = "xxx"
in Parent_ID

in  #"Added Custom"
```

or

```
let 

fn_Highest =  (n as text) as text =>
   let
    Parent_ID = "xxx"
  in Parent_ID,

// some comment here since comments start with two slashes
Table1 = #table({"Key1"},{{"Auto"},{"Bus"},{"Autobus"}, {"Car"}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Table1, "Custom", each fn_Highest("ddd"))
in  #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Can't I add it after?

Comment: yes. edited.  Please toggle checkmark to accept answer and mark question as solved

Comment: How can I use the function after declaring it like that, to round the values of a column?

Comment: Rounding is built into powerquery. But in general, transform the column somehow and replace the middle of the generated code with  each functionname(_).  Any tutorial on powerquery will show you how to use a function